# Ruby REXML: Get Value Of An XML Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, rexml

I am trying to put the values of some xml elements into an array using rexml. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
doc = Document.new("<data><title>This is one title</title><title>This is another title</title></data>")
XPath.each( doc, "*/title") { |element| 
    puts element.text
}
```

However, that outputs:

```
[<title> ... </>, <title> ... </>]
```

How can I get it to output an array containing "This is one title" and "This is another title"?

Comment: While `puts` may convert its argument its argument to a string anyway, you can have the XPath return the text node in the first place: `XPath.each(doc, "*/title/text()") {...`

Comment: That was it. I had to call the text() method inside of each. Thank you!

Comment: @LarsH: Sorry Lars, I only saw your comment after I posted my answer :(    Please post an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Dimitre: ok, will do. The reason I didn't post an answer in the first place is because I thought, based on lwburk's answer, that the problem was already solved.

Comment: @Jarred, glad your problem is solved. I converted my comment to an answer... so if you want to upvote it, there it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer, per request:

While `puts` may convert its argument its argument to a string anyway, you can have the XPath return the text node in the first place:

```
XPath.each(doc, "*/title/text()") {...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dimitre. I still think lwburk's answer is excellent, and he did more work than I did: he tested the OP's code, found the behavior was as desired, and brought the results back to the OP to check that the OP wasn't just forgetting something obvious.

Comment: @Dimitre, @LarsH - It's not just that `puts` is converting its output to a string, it's that `element.text` and selecting the `text()` in the first place are equivalent (given the OP's input).

Comment: @lwburk: ok. Dimitre - this is part of why I prefer lwburk's answer... he knows something about the Ruby XPath API, and I don't. :-)

Comment: I still wonder how in the world the OP got the output he's getting, with the code he showed.

Comment: @lwburk, LarsH,  OK guys, +1 for lwburk, too. I am interested primarily how using XPath can minimize the need for programming constructs in the host PL.

Comment: @lwburk: How did you manage to cheat the system and have more than one users referred to in your comment? I'd ask this as a SO question but I know it would be deleted in no time ... :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I just listed them independently, each with an `@`. I naively assumed it would work and I guess it did :) Also, +1 for *I am interested primarily how using XPath can minimize the need for programming constructs in the host PL.* I generally agree.

Comment: @lwburk: It doesn't work for me -- I get a message that only one user reference / comment is allowed :(

Comment: @Dimitre I wondered the same thing, how @lwburk referred to both of us with `@`. Then I decided the key was in the error message that said only one *additional* user; the author of the answer is automatically notified. However I just now tried putting both of you in this comment and it was accepted w/o error! Have the rules changed?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, I also noticed that sometimes this restriction isn't enforced. Probably SO bug :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about that? Here's a complete program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

doc = Document.new("<data><title>This is one title</title><title>This is another title</title></data>")
XPath.each( doc, "*/title") { |element|
    puts element.text
}
```

Output:

```
This is one title
This is another title
```

**Edit:** It sounds like the OP has moved on, but I think there should be some clarification added here for future visitors. I upvoted @LarsH's good answer, but it should be noted that, given the OP's specific input, `element.text` should produce *exactly the same output* as would result from selecting the `text()` nodes in the first place. From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Element.html#method-i-text):

> **text( path = nil )**
>   A convenience method which returns the String value
>   of the first child text element, if one exists, and nil otherwise.

The sample input given in the original question shows `<title>` elements containing only one text node in each case. Therefore, these two methods are the same (in this case).

However, pay attention to this important note:

> Note that an element may have multiple Text elements, perhaps
>   separated by other children. Be aware that this method only returns
>   the first Text node.

You can get *all* of an element's child text nodes using `texts()` (plural).

What I suspect a lot of people are really looking for is an equivalent of the DOM's `textContent` (or its illegitimate cousin `innerText`). Here's how you might do that in Ruby:

```
XPath.each(doc, "*/title") { |el|
    puts XPath.match(el,'.//text()').join
}
```

This joins all of the text *descendants* of each element into a single string.

The short answer is that there's no short answer. Which one of these you want, if any, is highly context-specific. The only requirement in the original question is to *"put the values of some xml elements into an array"*, which isn't really much of a specification.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the output I posted above is what I am getting. Is there any kind of configuration that could be causing this different output?

Comment: @Jarred, if it still matters, you could post more of your code, e.g. your require and include statements. But you probably already checked lwburk's and they are the same?